# I can't delete folder

Tags: directory, error-handling

How can I delete this folder [image]

Please Help me!

Folder Delete Error:

[image]
[image]

Comment: "Show more details"

Comment: You can not delete files you do not own. The 1st image has a "lock" icon so is not yours to delete. Drop to command line and use `sudo`

Comment: Delete blog folder but this folder is not delete. Error

Comment: So, how do I delete.sure to tell @Rinzwind

Answer (score 1):

Permission trouble ?
Type in a console `sudo rm -rf folderName` (be very careful as this command will erase the whole folder without warning, even if it is a system one)

Safer option, changing the permission of the folder (Adding to "All" users : "Writable") and erasing it afterward : `sudo chmod a+w folderName` and then `rm -rf folderName`

Comment: What's the "show more details" info ?

Comment: no working this command

Comment: what's the output ? What's the error message ?

Comment: @NickyDaniel Instead of simply saying _"not working"_ you should tell _what you typed and what error message you got_! Else nobody can help. There are only few very exotic situations where the suggested command does _not_ work.

Comment: Careful with that command too.

Comment: Safer option, as @EODCraftStaff outlined the potential disaster  : "sudo chmod a+w folderName" and then "rm -rf folderName"

Comment: Hey Men..! I Can Delete this folder. yayyyy!!!!.

Comment: Good for you. Please, take a look at https://askubuntu.com/tour to get the AskUbuntu's how-to (posting questions, sending details, voting and accepting answers and so on;)